# jQuery will not update textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML textarea defined in index.html defined as follows:

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows="12" readonly="7" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

I have a JavaScript file named `shared.js`. Right now, `shared.js` only has the following:

```
function appendToTextArea(id, text, stayOnCurrentLine) {
    var current = $(id).val();

    var newText = current + ' ' + text;
    if (!stayOnCurrentLine) {
        newStatus += '\n';          
    }
    $(id).val(newText);

    console.log($(id).val());   
}
```

Index.html is successfully referencing shared.js. It even calls `appendToTextArea` just fine. I'm calling the code from a function in index.html called myButtonClick.

```
function myButtonClick() {
    appendToTextArea('#myTextArea', 'Hello', false);
    appendToTextArea('#myTextArea', 'How', false);
    appendToTextArea('#myTextArea', 'are', false);
    appendToTextArea('#myTextArea', 'you', false);
}
```

When the above is called, the text of `myTextArea` is never updated. However, in the console, I see no errors. In addition, I can see the text exactly how I would expect it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `newStatus` is undefined. Seems to work fine once you fix that http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kc6s3e2u/

Comment: This is more relevant jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kc6s3e2u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `newStatus` as empty string and concatenate it with outputted string:

```
function appendToTextArea(id, text, stayOnCurrentLine) {
    var current = $(id).val();
    var newStatus = "";
    var newText = current + ' ' + text;
    if (!stayOnCurrentLine) {
        newStatus += '\n';
    }
    $(id).val(newText + newStatus);

    console.log($(id).val());
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: @ZachTempleton - You do see that the fiddles in the comments to your question work though right?

Comment: @j08691Yes. I'm wondering if it is because my JavaScript code is in a different file?

Comment: @ZachTempleton It could or not. You have to provide concrete sample replicating your issue if you want specific help regarding it. BTW, how do you debug it? Is the method called or not? Etc...

Comment: @j08691. I can see your fiddle working. However, it is still not working in my environment. I am debugging by printing values to the console window via `console.log`. The values that get printed to the console window are correct. This made me believe that I had a typo. However, everything looks correct. I even tried a) Adding just a textbox instead of a textarea and the same bug appears there. b) Using `$(id).attr('val', (newText+newStatus))` and this did not work either. Its so weird, its just the UI that isn't updating.

Comment: @ZachTempleton Be aware, i'm not `j08691`... :) It could be many reasons, without seeing any sample, that's quite impossible to help. For example, maybe you are using duplicate IDs?!